# ViewPager - Hide number of pages

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm building my Android App using Viewpagers, and I built a ListView that takes 8 seconds to show the full Items.

The page doesn't update the view automatically, thats why the Listview appears empty when it is shown for the first time.

So, I was thinking about creating a new page called loading, and hide the page with the listview, and only show it when the Listview items are already there.

To do that, I would like to know how can I hide pages.

I tried to use an Handler and change the number of pages after 8 seconds, but it didn't work, can you guys give me any idea of how can I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing you are populating that list view with an `AsyncTask`. Override the `onPostExecute()` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` or whatever you need to make it display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't  create a new page called loading,it is not a good way to solve it. You can u get data in oncreat first time,then update data by a `timer`or `handler`+`timertask` and so on.